# How to deselect item of listbox?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `ListBox` that when an item is selected, it is shown in a label as well. However, when I want to remove the selected item, program  breaks and shows a `NullReferenceException`.

My code:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = "Your Selected: " + listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = "";
    listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(listBox1.SelectedIndex);
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, did you want to deselect or remove the selected item? `listbox1.ClearSelected();` will do this, but won't remove the item.

Comment: Can you see what is throwing the null reference, i.e. what object is null? I think Dmitry's reply below is probably the answer, but it would be worth including the info in your question.

Comment: why? I want Remove Single Item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may appear, that there's *no selected item* in the listbox, so you have to check for that:

```
   private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       label1.Text = null == listBox1.SelectedItem 
         ? ""
         : "Your Selected: " + listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
   }

   private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     // Looks redundant, listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged will do 
     //label1.Text = "";    

     // Deselect item, but not remove it
     if (listBox1.SelectedIndex >= 0)
       listBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;

     // In case you want to remove the item (not deselect) - comment out the code below
     // if (listBox1.SelectedIndex >= 0)
     //   listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(listBox1.SelectedIndex);
   }
```

**Edit**: as for *counting* listbox items, there's *no event* fo this in the current listbox implementation. So you have to do it manually:

```
  if (listBox1.SelectedIndex >= 0) {
    listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(listBox1.SelectedIndex);

    lbItemsCount.Text = listBox1.Items.Count.ToString();
  }
```

Comment: changing `label1.Text = null == listBox1.SelectedItem` to `label1.Text = (null == listBox1.SelectedItem)`would increase the readability. Moreover `string.Empty` is better than `""`

Comment: Good! Now I want Remove Single Item of Listbox. But do not be.

Comment: @user5550711: `if (listBox1.SelectedIndex >= 0) listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(listBox1.SelectedIndex);` see my edit

Comment: Excellent! Solved.
Thanks my friend.

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko: Next Question: How to can create dynamic variable, counter for lines of listbox.items and show in form??? dynamic for when add/remove item in listbox...

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use click event of the list box , if we do not want to double click the one list box item for the deselection of another list items.
ex:

```
private void ListBox_Right_Click(strong textobject sender, EventArgs e)
{
Btn_Left.Enabled = ListBox_Right.SelectedIndex >= 0;
ListBox_Left.ClearSelected(); // to clear the list selection/highlight
Btn_Right.Enabled = false; // for my specification
}
}



private void ListBox_Left_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

Btn_Right.Enabled = ListBox_Left.SelectedIndex >= 0;
ListBox_Right.ClearSelected();  //to clear the list selection/highlight

Btn_Left.Enabled = false;// for my specification
}
```